# OkHttp3Connection code 403 error

Tags: java, neo4j, okhttp

I have done some queries to the database and they usually work but when I am trying to do it in the current class, I get the following error:

```
{"code":403,"success":false,"message":"Forbidden, No token provided"}
```

Both classes are too long to post here, and thus I think this is all I can provide:

```
SET_USER_STAR_COUNT = URL + "setUserProfileStars";

JSONObject request_data=new JSONObject();
try
{
    request_data.put("newscore",newStars);
} catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


OkHttp3Connection.doOkHttp3Connection("", Services_Url_class.SET_USER_STAR_COUNT, OkHttp3Connection.Request_type.POST, request_data, new OkHttp3Connection.OkHttp3RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result, String user_tag) {
        System.out.println("oO" + result);
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(String error, String user_tag)
    {}
});
```

And here is the controller:

```
Router.post('/setUserProfileStars', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.decoded.name;
    var newStars = req.decoded.newscore;
    var response = [];
    var addStars = 'MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.username = "' + username + '" SET n.stars = "'+ newStars +'" RETURN n.stars AS totalStars';

    dbneo4j.cypher({
        query: addStars
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send({
                code: 9325,
                message: 'error encountered',
                error: err
            }).status(9325);
        }
        response.push(data);
        res.send({
            code: 200,
            message: 'success',
            data: response
        }).status(200);
    });
});
```

If there is anything else I can provide then I will do so.

The error comes when I try to print the `result`. My question is why is it doing so and how can I debug and check what is wrong with it?

Comment: Don't use the Javascript tag for Java questions, they are not the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 Forbidden indicates that the server is refusing to process your request because you are not authorized. According to the message details, the server expects an authorization token to be passed as a header. You will have to work with the server to determine what "token" it expects.

Comment: Where would I place the "token"?

Comment: You pass the token, whatever it is, in your request header. The problem is obtaining a valid token. Typically, you would have to contact an authorization server, authenticate with it, and it would return the token to you. How that is implemented varies.

Comment: That actually helped me figure out what was wrong, thank you,